# Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging

Tags: testing, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

This question is related to Sonarqube. I want to run my c++ project, on executing scanner(this scanner code generated after creating new project on sonarqube) from my computer, i am getting this error.

```
...
ERROR: SonarQube server [https://sonarqube.factset.com] can not be reached
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 1.405s
INFO: Final Memory: 3M/20M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarQube
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:85)
...

        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:221)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.shaded.okhttp.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:81)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.callUrl(ServerConnection.java:113)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:98)
        at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.BootstrapIndexDownloader.getIndex(BootstrapIndexDownloader.java:39)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
        ... 44 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
        ... 50 more
ERROR:
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jenkins: org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarQube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57038682/jenkins-org-sonarsource-scanner-api-internal-scannerexception-unable-to-execut)